# Deploy two django app with nginx but the second app is directed on the first

Tags: django, nginx

I am using nginx server to realise 2 servers block. My apps is made with django and gunicorn. What happen is that the first project working well but the second link or is directed to the second like if the second server block redirect in the first. I have the same name for my django project but in 2 differents virtualenv

my first conf for the first project

```
 upstream prod_app_server {

     server unix:/webapps/projet1/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0; 
 }

 server {
     server_name app.exemple.com;
     client_max_body_size 4G;
    location /static/ {
        root /webapps/projet1/django_project;
    }

    location /media/ {
       root /webapps/projet1/django_project;
    }

 location / {

     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     if (!-f $request_filename) {
         proxy_pass http://prod_app_server;
         break;
     }
 }
```

}

my second conf for the second project

```
 upstream prod2_app_server {

     server unix:/webapps/projet2/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0; 
 }

 server {
     server_name app2.exemple.com;
     client_max_body_size 4G;
    location /static/ {
        root /webapps/projet2/django_project;
    }

    location /media/ {
       root /webapps/projet2/django_project;
    }

 location / {

     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     if (!-f $request_filename) {
         proxy_pass http://prod2_app_server;
         break;
     }
 }

}
```

my gunicorn conf for the project 1

```
 NAME="projet1"                                  
 DJANGODIR=/webapps/projet1/django_project            
 SOCKFILE=/webapps/projet1/run/gunicorn.sock 
 USER=axit                 
 GROUP=webapps                                      
 NUM_WORKERS=15     
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_project.settings             
 DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=django_project.wsgi
```

my gunicorn conf for the project 2

```
 NAME="projet2"                                  
 DJANGODIR=/webapps/projet2/django_project            
 SOCKFILE=/webapps/projet2/run/gunicorn.sock 
 USER=axit                 
 GROUP=webapps                                      
 NUM_WORKERS=15     
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django_project.settings             
 DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=django_project.wsgi
```

Comment: If they both have the same host and same location only one will ever be served.

Comment: no the location is different with two gunicorn different socket